# Accessing Rails Class/Model Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, methods

I am new to rails and am figuring out the best ways to write certain methods.

I am trying to write a method that belongs to a certain model and can be accessed without initiating an instance. So far I have this under my class PaymentNotification < ActiveRecord::Base

```
def url
   url_for(:controller => 'payment_notifications', :only_path => false)
end
```

The problem here is that I need to do this to access the url

```
n = PaymentNotification.new
n.url
```

In my code, I want to be able to write PaymentNotification.url to access the method relevant to that model.

Maybe I am thinking about this the wrong way and someone can guide me. Basically, what I am trying to achieve is that each model can have its set of methods and attributes so that they all are organized and I know from the code which file each method is declared in, instead of just calling a

```
payment_notification_url
```

which may be located in any of the irrelevant initialization files. I saw helper methods but it seems like i still won't be able to use a dot syntax and will have to write something like "payment_notification_url" to access my url

Any ideas on the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a class method via the self keyword.

```
def self.url
   url_for(:controller => 'payment_notifications', :only_path => false)
end
```

Then you can use PaymentNotification.url

```
class A
  def self.a
    p "Class method"
  end

  def b
    p "Instance Method"
  end
end

A.a   #Class method
#A.b #NoMethodError

a = A.new
a.b #Instance Method
#a.a    #NoMethodError
```

Comment: i tried that but it seems like the "url_for" becomes unavailable at that scope. Any idea why? This is the error I see:

undefined method `url_for' for #<Class:0x10a731120>

Comment: The reason is because url_for is an instance method and not a class method.  It cannot be used in the context of a class.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for